# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (within Promise.all)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios, use-effect

I am creating React practice project and I am still dealing with this *kind of error* (Objects are not valid as a React child). More in screenshot below.

[Thrown error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqzsY.png)

***You can see problem part of code in that screenshot too**.*

**Some explanation:** This piece of code is *a part inside an `useEffect`* (*this useEffect content is executed only if `fixturesIds` aren't undefined)*. Then some *get requests are pushed* into an array `predictionList` and they are resolved together in `Promise.all`. *Promise.all returns an array* which I map to get required data. This all (`prediction.value.data`) *is setted as a state* (`setFixturesDetails`).

`Prediction.value.data` looks like: [{..}, {..}, {..}, {..}]

*It worked very well, when I logged it into console.*

But when I tried to *use this array of objects as a props in Component* (see below) ...

```
return (
    <div className='App'>
      {fixturesDetails.length > 0 ? (
        fixturesDetails.map((details) => (
          <Prediction
            homeTeam={details.teams.home.name}
            awayTeam={details.teams.away.name}
            winner={details.predictions.winner}
          />
        ))
      ) : (
        <h2>Loading</h2>
      )}
    </div>
```

...it *has started to throw a mentioned Error*.

**Loading** appears **normally** and **it crashes** when **fixturesDetails are setted** (`fixturesDetails.length` > 0 is true),

***so instead of showing Prediction component it shows that error.***

Any ideas why does it throw that error? I researched a lot but I am still not able to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you get when u console log the `fixturesDetails.map((details) => (<Component/>))`. Can you also show your Prediction component code

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the implementation of the `Prediction` component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have just figured it out.

The problem is that it is not possible to use object as a props in JSX syntax.

I logged all my props in the console and found out that one of my props is really an object.

Solution is pretty clear, just choose right property inside an object. If there is complicated API with nested objects it can be very easy to overlook you are actually returning an object within prop.

*Maybe it will help someone someday:)*